# Coroutine scope in CustomView Android Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom view in which there is a function where I want to show a view for some seconds. To use the delay function I need a coroutine scope. How should I implement it? Can declaring coroutine scope in custom view cause any problem?

First was thinking if we can get lifecycleScope in it

Comment: Are you trying to show a composable for small duration of time or is there anything else we should if yes then please elaborate the requirment

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewTreeLifecycleOwner#(android.view.View).get()) to get the lifecycle owner, and get the lifecycle scope from that. But you should treat it as nullable since it's possible the View isn't currently attached to a lifecycle owner.

```
val View.lifecycleScope: CoroutineScope? 
    get() = ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(this).lifecycleScope
```

Therefore, you should be careful about where you use this. If you use it in the constructor, it will still be unattached and you'll get `null`, so using `lifecycleScope?.launch { }` won't do anything. You might consider overriding `onAttachedToWindow()` and starting your work there. I think it should have the lifecycle owner attached by then.

Also be aware that there may be cases where the view never gets attached to a hierarchy that has a LifecycleOwner. For example, if you use it in an Activity that doesn't descend from ComponentActivity, or you use it in a native AlertDialog instead of a DialogFragment.